# C++ Windows: How to close a console window?

Tags: c++, windows, console, exit

I have a console window opened using "AllocConsole()`, besides the main Win32 window. The console window opens before the main one.

When I close the main window and the program returns from main function, the console remains open (and so does the process). It actually gets stuck somewhere in `ntdll`, as the debugger shows on pausing the program from Visual Studio 2012.

Closing it by clicking on the `X` button exits the process, but closing it with `FreeConsole()` doesn't, the process remains working windowless.

`CloseWindow(GetConsoleWindow())` doesn't close it, it minimizes it (!?!).

`PostMessage(GetConsoleWindow(),WM_QUIT,0,0)` closes the window, but the process still remains working (visually, this is the same as "FreeConsole()`).

Occasionally, the program exits in the right way, but clicking on the `X` button works every time.

How do I do the same thing that clicking on the `X` button does?

Comment: You don't have to close the console window, it should disappear by itself when you return from main and exit your main thread (along with the other threads). If you are not doing something nasty then the console window is not the cause of your program getting stuck. Your program would probably hang without the console window too but first lets try things without allocating a console. Getting stuck in ntdll doesn't necessary mean that your console window is responsible, it may be the end result of something previously done by the gui/logic part of the app.

Comment: @AlexFarber As far as I know you can have only one console window per process but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Vladivarius `CloseWindow()` is expected to minimize the window (check the docs), it is an ancient function from the dark ages and it has been given a terrible/confusing name. If you want to simulate pressing the X button of a window then send the window a `WM_CLOSE` message.

Comment: So, you have Windows application with additional console? Maybe you can get the same effect by changing the application type to SUBSYSTEM:Console. In this case you don't need to use AllocConsole.

Comment: @pasztorpisti post your comment about WM_CLOSE as an answer(or even better, both comments), it worked. That was what I wanted to do, just got confused and used WM_QUIT instead -.- Also, there is probably something wrong with the rest of the program, as nvoglv32.dll threads remain running and call stack is just ripe with calls to it and ntdll. Must be a really nasty OpenGL leak :/

Comment: @AlexFarber Good point, that works well. I've used `AllocConsole()` only when I wanted to open a console for some random printffing (debug) or to open console from a dll for similar purposes.

Comment: @Vladivarius Sounds bad, video drivers are often full of hacks and bugs anyway... You should probably track that down at some point. If its possible try to turn off different render features in your program and if the program-exit-hangup disappears then you may be able to narrow down the location of the bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `PostMessage(wnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)` to close the console window, but the problem is probably somewhere else in your program even if this works as a hotfix. The console window should close/disappear automatically when you return from your `main()` or `WinMain()`.

Comment: I think it is worth noticing that "HANDLE wnd" of the running console could be acquired with "wnd = GetConsoleWindow()". Works nice, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to destroy the console within the `WM_DESTROY` message using `FreeConsole`. I usually do this all in a class that wraps my console. This way it can redirect input/output to the console in the constructor and reset input/output in the destructor as well as alloc/destroy the console respectively.

However, without using a class or any wrappers, it can be done as follows..

Example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <streambuf>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

std::streambuf *CinBuffer, *CoutBuffer, *CerrBuffer;
std::fstream ConsoleInput, ConsoleOutput, ConsoleError;

void RedirectIO()
{
    CinBuffer = std::cin.rdbuf();
    CoutBuffer = std::cout.rdbuf();
    CerrBuffer = std::cerr.rdbuf();
    ConsoleInput.open("CONIN$", std::ios::in);
    ConsoleOutput.open("CONOUT$", std::ios::out);
    ConsoleError.open("CONOUT$", std::ios::out);
    std::cin.rdbuf(ConsoleInput.rdbuf());
    std::cout.rdbuf(ConsoleOutput.rdbuf());
    std::cerr.rdbuf(ConsoleError.rdbuf());
}

void ResetIO()
{
    ConsoleInput.close();
    ConsoleOutput.close();
    ConsoleError.close();
    std::cin.rdbuf(CinBuffer);
    std::cout.rdbuf(CoutBuffer);
    std::cerr.rdbuf(CerrBuffer);
    CinBuffer = NULL;
    CoutBuffer = NULL;
    CerrBuffer = NULL;
}

LRESULT __stdcall WindowProcedure(HWND Hwnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            AllocConsole();
            RedirectIO();
            std::cout<<"HELLO CONSOLE!"<<std::endl;
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            std::cout<<"BYE-BYE CONSOLE!"<<std::endl;
            ResetIO();
            FreeConsole();
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(Hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
};

int main()
{
    WNDCLASSEX WndClass =
    {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, WindowProcedure,
        0, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION),
        LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1),
        NULL, "WindowClass", LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION)
    };

    if(RegisterClassEx(&WndClass))
    {
        HWND WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, "WindowClass", "Window Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        if(WindowHandle)
        {
            MSG msg = {NULL};
            ShowWindow(WindowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
            while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the exact thing I am doing(your idea about WM_DESTROY) and it's not exiting the process :/ Looks like the problem is in the way I set up the console, now it works when I have copied it from you. Indeed I was surprised that my code appeared to be working after just copy-pasting it from somewhere else than stackoverflow xD

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <windows.h>

HWND myConsole = GetConsoleWindow(); //window handle
ShowWindow(myConsole, 0); //handle window
```

The solution I wound up using was to set Linker->System->SubSystem to "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)" instead of "Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)". This makes the console not even appear, which avoids flickering. The second solution was better for me, and it rendered the first obsolete.