# How to Close Console Window with code in Visual studios C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've built a small Menu system. and I'm looking to add an option to Close the console window that pops up when code runs but I haven't found anything to do so yet. Can anyone help?

This is the code I have so far following what Paddy said in the comments bellow

```
void Menu::Output() {
    HWND WINAPI GetConsoleWindow(void);

    int number;
    cin >> number;

    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        GetterAndSetters();
        break;
    case 2:
        OverloadingConstructors();
        break;
    case 3:
        ThisKeyword();
        break;
    case 4:
        Constructor_INIT_List();
        break;
    case 5:
        DestroyWindow;
        //FreeConsole();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "nothing selected" << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nType BACK to return to Menu \nEnter Here>> " << flush;

    string password;
    cin >> password;

    if (password == "back") {
        system("CLS");
        MenuOver();
    }
}
```

The code running in Case 5 is not having the desired effect. I'm just wondering have I done it right?

Comment: You can call FreeConsole, and if your process is the only process using the console, it will close. Is that not enough?

Comment: I'm looking to close the console window entirely so that it takes me back to code

Comment: Have you tried obtaining the handle to the console window via [GetConsoleWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) and then calling either `CloseWindow` or `DestroyWindow`?

Comment: have I put the code in correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you could use `SendMessage()` to close window.

```
HWND hwnd= GetConsoleWindow();
int number;
cin >> number;
switch (number)
{
//....

case 5:
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    //FreeConsole();
    break;
}
```

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271920/c-windows-how-to-close-a-console-window).

Comment: Thanks for the help